# approximate this fancy looking double integral

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, polar-coordinates

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{1}r^5\sin^22\theta\left(1-r^2 \right)^2\sqrt{1+\left(1+ \cos^2\theta \right)36r^2  }\hspace{1mm}drd\theta$$

I tried integrating myself, spent many hours but could not figure out really anything, even used wolfram, it says time up!

Comment: The Maple command $$VectorCalculus:-int(r^5*sin(2*theta)^2*(-r^2+1)^2*sqrt(1+((1+cos(theta)^2)*36)*r^2), [r, theta] = Rectangle(0 .. 1, 0 .. 2*Pi));$$ outputs $$-{\frac {25123\,\sqrt {2}\pi }{59861514240}}-{\frac {312529639111\,
\sqrt {73}{\it EllipticK} \left( {\frac {6\,\sqrt {73}}{73}} \right) 
}{7647308444160}}+{\frac {8297474263\,\sqrt {73}{\it EllipticE}
 \left( {\frac {6\,\sqrt {73}}{73}} \right) }{104757649920}}+{\frac {
25123\,\sqrt {73}{\it EllipticPi} \left( 1/2,{\frac {6\,\sqrt {73}}{73
}} \right) }{2184945269760}}.$$

Comment: I like $$Digits := 13; VectorCalculus:-int(r^5*sin(2*theta)^2*(-r^2+1)^2*sqrt(1+((1+cos(theta)^2)*36)*r^2), [r, theta] = Rectangle(0 .. 1, 0 .. 2*Pi), numeric, epsilon = 10^{-10}) $$ $$0.2709739978682 $$ more.

Comment: wow, thanks for that

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the $\theta$ and only considering $r$ basically this has the form $$r\cdot p(r^2)\cdot \sqrt{1+c\cdot r^2}$$
where $p$ is a polynomial. So you can try to substitute $t=1+c r^2$, so you end up with an integral over $\frac{1}{2c} p(t) \cdot \sqrt{t}$, which should pose no problem.

This still leaves the integral over $\theta$, which maybe you can attack with the usual bag of tricks, like using symmetries and so on.